# Error in inclusion of <QtNetwork> in cpp file of a BB10 app development

Tags: blackberry-10, qtnetwork

I am currently working on BB10 app development.

I was trying out some demo apps given in Blackberry's Developer Portal.

I am currently working on an app based on [HTTP Communication](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_comm/networking/wrapping_up.html).

When I build the project it gives an error
`fatal error: QtNetwork: No such file or directory`.

Also in the cpp file is giving a `?` in front of inclusion statement `#include <QtNetwork>`
 saying `Unresolved Inclusion : <QtNetwork>`

Can anyone help me out in resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

QtNetwork  is a module, not a class to import. Write for exemple:

```
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
```